# App review, found serious bug after approved

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

My situation is

> 1. Created app for first upload
> 2. Set release date in July 2014 (so that I control when to release)
> 3. App is approved
> 4. I found serious bug in the app
> 5. App status is 'ready for sale' but I didn't find it in app store (because the release date is in July?)

My question is how can I upload another binary to fix the bug before people can download?

Thanks!

Comment: Just upload an update with a new version number. Update will be approved and the new version(updated) will be released at the time that you specified.

Answer (score 1):

You could also withdraw your current version from being on the store (or put it on hold) and then resubmit a new version.

In the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide's Viewing & Changing your App's Status & Availability section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW1), one of the app statuses is "Developer Removed From Sale".

Answer (score 1):

Set your release date to a future date (so people can not download it) and simply submit a new update. Once the new update is approved set the release date back to a past day, then app will be ready for release immediately.